# Removing an iframe with jquery whenever something is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I want to remove an iframe whenever anything is clicked. I put this code:

```
    $('*').on('click',function(){
                $('iframe').remove();

     });
```

However, the problem that I have is that the iframe chases the mouse. So basically, I get to click the iframe each time,.. since the iframe hasnt got a click event, that script wont work.

I was looking for any alternative solution that would trap a click event..and will enable the disappearance of the iframe. Can a web application recognise a left-click on a mouse, even when it doesnt have to be on something..

That could solve my problem.. But i found no solution on the net, no matter how much I have looked!

Comment: Just as concept. Get position and height/width of iframe. Create div with `position:absolute;height/width` of iframe and check clicking in iframe area. And add event on click for `body`

Comment: There is no way for the click event inside the iframe to be delegated, or bubbled up to the document body that houses the iframe. If you can manage to click the document somehow, then it's easy as pie. If your mouse click is always received by the iframe, I believe there is no way. I hope someone proves me wrong.

Comment: the problem is that there is no way to put a div above the iframe,,but you can put an iframe above the div

Comment: why not wrap the iframe with a div and make the div disappear with the iframe inside?

Comment: cause the iframe captures the click and not the div. try it yourself.. it is impossible to place a div on an iframe. and even if it was possible, that is not the goal. The goal is for the user to click on the iframe, but having some browser event to be triggered..so that i can capture it. The only solution to this, is to capture a click..no matter if it is on an element or not.. but if you have a working solution I would like to hear it

Comment: Why is it impossible to place a div on an iframe? You can very easily do that. All you need to do is position the div exactly over the iframe with CSS, ensuring the z-index of this div is higher than the iframe.

Comment: As I said, even if it worked,.. that wouldnt give me what I want. I want the user to be able to click on the iframe... so if i put a div above,.. he wouldnt be able to click on the iframe, wouldnt he? unless if I had some event for the iframe that when clicked, it could call the div to come forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to close the iframe on **any** click, then covering the iframe with an invisible div should achieve what you're after.

Check out this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6g4KQ/

Besides doing this, there's no way of accessing the click inside the iframe - unless you have access to the content of iframe, which I'm guessing you don't.